# How to assign something in a for loop?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

Do you know how to assign these in a loop so it's less exhaustive?

```
number1 <- as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, my_list[1]))
number2 <- as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, my_list[2]))
number3 <- as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, my_list[3]))
number4 <- as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, my_list[4]))
number5 <- as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, my_list[5]))
```

I have tried:

```
for (i in 1:5) {
(number(i) <- as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, my_list[(i)])))
}
```

which doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to extract all the elements of a list in a data frame, you can use `assign`:

```
# Example list with 5 elements
my_list <- list(1:5, 1:5, 1:5, 1:5, 1:5)

for(xx in seq_along(my_list)){
  assign(paste0("number", xx), as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, my_list[xx])))
}
```

This will create 5 data frames in your global environment named `number1`, `number2`, ..., `number5`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `assign()` function to do that. Please use the following example to get the idea and edit your code:

```
for (i in 1:5) {
  m <- data.frame(x=rnorm(10), y=rnorm(10))
  assign(paste0('number',i), m)
}
number1
number2
number3
number4
number5
```

Best of Luck.

Comment: You still explicitly create data frames one at a time and then have a loop. I think the point is to avoid explicitly creating data frames , while also adding the values the data frames will contain.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me @user2554330 I agree. The code was edited.